# How to use Aircrack-ng when knowing part of the password?

Tags: linux, wireless, wpa2, password-cracking

Let's say I know the password starts with "1234" and after that there is a commonly used password. I would like to use the word list I have for the second part of the password, but to include somehow the "1234" before every password of the word list while cracking.
It would be extremely time consuming to write a program that makes a new word list out of the normal one with the "1234" in front of every pass and run it on some big word list.

I guess there should be a command that can help me with that, if not, I guess I should start coding.

PS: I need it for educational purposes.

Comment: Why would such a program would be time consuming to write?  it is a single line of python.

Comment: I did already wrote a neat java program that does the job, but the time consuming thing is to take every wordlist and make a new one out of it. When the list is 1GB it takes a lot of computational time. That is what I meant. Nevertheless, I do it this way now since there is no specific code to use while cracking.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it! It will append 1234 beginning of each line in your wordlist.

sed 's/^/1234/' wordlist.txt > newWordList.txt

Answer (score 1):

There are open source programs designed to make wordlists based on your criteria, like Crunch: http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/.  This will make it easy to generate wordlists with specific permutations.  On the other hand, if you just need to take one wordlist and add a simple prefix to each line, almost every interpreted/scripted language can do that in a single line of code.  Bash would look like this (replace single quote with tick):

`for $i in 'cat ./wordlist'; do echo "1234"$i >> ./new-wordlist; done`